How can I use an FET for a 5V load with a 3.3 V gate control?
This surely has been asked before but I can't find a solution to this simple beginner issue.
I have a load that needs 5 V and a few milliamps to run. I also have a digital 3.3 V signal that should turn its supply on and off. The minus of the load should always be grounded. My first approach used an N-channel FET.

This was my first approach.  I didn't think too much about it and found it intuitive and even ordered PCBs with that exact design.
I made the most common beginner mistake regarding transistors — the gate voltage is relative to the source, which won't be 0 V anymore because the load is in between, which led to some in-between state.

This would've been my second approach, but the issue here is that the load is not grounded when the gate is low, which will also lead to issues in my application.

Now, here I changed the N-channel FET for a P-channel FET, thinking I finally found the solution. The gate being inverted doesn't matter. Now, however, it doesn't matter if the control GATE is on or off, the FET gate will now either see -5 V or -1.7 V, which are both below the threshold so it does nothing.
I'm pretty sure I'm missing something. Do I need multiple FETs to have an elegant solution to this?

In the datasheet for the transistor you got a minimum Vgs = -0.8V to -2V.
This means you can not really be sure to ever turn OFF the transistor. So either you need to add another transistor and resistor that control the gate of BSS84. This is shown below

You also have to consider how fast you want to switch BSS84, as the 10K resistor is compromise between switching speed and power consumption. This depends on your application.
Or you can search for a transistor with a higher threshold voltage.

So putting another BSS123 between the Control and BSS84 Gate would work? Since the Gate has no load it wont arise the first issue and fix the last issue...?

@Kaisky The N-channel and the 10k pullup resistor to 5V effectively translates your control signal from 3.3V to 5V, allowing you to fully control the P-channel. This type of structure using both FETs is very common for high side switching, although I would reconsider the actual part numbers which right now have a high Rds(on). You can also buy integrated solutions which use the exact same internal structure. https://www.onsemi.com/download/data-sheet/pdf/fdc6330l-d.pdf

You should change BSS84 to 2N6845.


But you could find better MOSFET to do the job ...

Is the idea to purposely pick a MOSFET with a high threshold voltage so the 3.3V control is enough to turn it off? If so, I would add this clarification to your answer.
